# C# Unusual Instantiation of a Method/Property

Tags: c#, methods, properties

Can someone please explain the code and its use. This was a .net 3.5 app. I have never seen anything like this before:

```
int IList.Add(object value) => this.Add(value as Trigger)
```

this Code was outside of and not part of any Method, but inside the main class.

I get an error on this code, but to fix the error, I need to understand the what why and hows.

I am sorry, I do not have the full code, I cant provide more information, I am just wanting to understand why this is the way it is.

Comment: That's an expression-bodied member, introduced in C# 6.

Comment: It's an explicitly implemented interface that uses C# 6 expression bodied member syntax.

Comment: C# 6 can only be compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  - I am guessing its obsolete now then?

Comment: @Chris, quite the opposite, C# 6 is the latest iteration of C#.

Comment: @jsve - Oh, I must be obsolete then ;0) - Thank You Guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unfold

```
int IList.Add(object value) => this.Add(value as Trigger)
```

like this:

```
int IList.Add(object value) { return this.Add(value as Trigger); }
```

As comments pointed out, the former is a C# 6 language construction, which requires the latest language compiler, like the one packaged with Visual Studio .Net 2015. Prior compiler versions will generate a syntax error that you've mentioned.

Language version (sometimes MS refers to it as "tools version") is not related to .Net framework though. You can use C# 6 with 3.5 as well as other .Net frameworks.